# Import data from Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have an Oracle database in a remote server. I want to import data from it to SQL Server on a local machine using a stored procedure or job shedule but I don't know how can I do it.

Comment: Have you looked at the Migration assistant that Microsoft has?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/create-oracle-linked-server-query-data-from-oracle-to-sql-server.aspx) you have nice article how to link oracle to your SQL Server and query it.

For data import you can you SELECT INTO statement or make SSIS package for that.

Comment: plz can you tell me how can I import data with the Select Statement? thank you so much :)

Comment: when i try to use link oracle to sql i obtain this error:
An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
help plz

Comment: SELECT INTO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101739/sql-server-select-into-existing-table

Comment: An exception is probably result of wrong syntax. Have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091960/sql-server-linked-server-example-query